# Is there a typical config or property file format and library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, configuration-files

I need a set of key-value pairs for configuration read in from a file. I tried using show on a Data.Map and it doesn't look at all like what I want. It seems this is something many others might have already done so I'm wondering if there is a standard way to do it and what library to use.

Comment: taotree: Not sure if you, the asker, are informed about edits, so... "I've recently used configurator - which was easy enough. I suggest you try that one!"  It really is simple and full featured.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Go to [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hackage.html).
2. Click on "[packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html)"
3. Search for "config".
4. Notice [ConfigFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConfigFile)([TH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConfigFileTH)), [EEConfig](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EEConfig), and [tconfig](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tconfig).
5. Read the Haddock documentation
6. Select a couple and implement your task.
7. Blog about your findings so the rest of us can learn from your new found expertise (thanks!).

EDIT:
I've recently used [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator) - which was easy enough.  I suggest you try that one!

(Yes, yes.  If I took my own advice I would have made a blog for you all)

Comment: "Read the docs" - I find that one very hard when learning haskell.

Comment: Thank you man! <- Sounds a bit harsh, but I appreciate that you wrote the process how to do that, so we have a solution for same kind of problems :-).

Comment: Glad you found it useful @peni4142.  These days I'm mostly using dhall for internal configurations and tomland for things that need to be shared publicly (a toml parser).

Answer (score 8):

The configuration category on Hackage should list all relevant libraries:
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Configuration

I have researched the topic myself now, and my conclusion is:

- [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator) is very good, but it's currently only for user-edited configurations. The application only reads the configuration and cannot modify it. So it's more for server-side applications.
- [tconfig](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tconfig)  has a a simple API and looked like it was what I wanted, maybe a bit raw, until I realized it's [unmaintained](https://github.com/Raynes/TConfig/issues/8#issuecomment-38632343) and that some [commits](https://github.com/Raynes/TConfig/commit/776aaeb77bab876d07bd3968607fb9d80c94a950) which are really important to use the app are applied on github but the hackage package was not updated

Other solutions didn't look like they'd work for me, I didn't like the API, but every application (and tastes) are different.

I think using JSON for instance is not a good solution because at least with Aeson when you add new settings in a new release, the old JSON without the new member from the previous version won't load. Also, i find that solution a bit verbose.

The conclusion of my research is that I wrote my own library, [app-settings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/app-settings), which aims to be key-value, read-write, with a as succint and type-safe API as possible. And you'll find it also in the hackage links for the configurations category that I gave.

So to summarize, I think [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator) is the standard for read-only configurations (and it's very powerful too, you can split the configuration file with imports for instance). For read-write there are many small libraries, some unmaintained, and no real standard I think.

**UPDATE 2018** be sure to look at [dhall](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang)

Answer (score 4):

I'd also suggest just using `Text.JSON` or one of the yaml libraries available (I prefer JSON myself, but...).

Answer (score 3):

The [configfile package](https://github.com/jgoerzen/configfile/wiki) looks like what you want.